# Get active elastic beanstalk environment info via AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, blue-green-deployment

How can I retrieve information using the AWS CLI about the active elastic beanstalk instance setup in a blue/green manner (where two environments are running side by side).

Running the following command gives me an array of environments for my application:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environments --application-name MyApp
```

Although I would prefer a command which only returned the active environment (and not the inactive).

Is the most accurate way to tell this by `CNAME` containing the string `inactive` from the command output?

The specific piece of data which I require is `EnvironmentName`.

Answer (score 2):

You need several aws cli to find it out.

#### Get the hosted zones ids

```
aws route53 list-hosted-zones
```

#### filter out target zone id

#### list elastic beanstalk applications

```
aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environments --application-name MyApp | jq -r '.Environments[].CNAME'
```

export its CNAME

#### get the record sets in that zone id.

```
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id <hosted-zone-id>
```

#### filter out the CNAME which you get from above `elasticbeanstalk` cli